# How to parse xml file with <pair key = "..."> </pair> format

Tags: python, xml

I hope to parse a '.xml' file using python. The format of the file is as follows:

```
<root><dm_log_packet>
    <pair key ="type_id">LTE_PHY_Serv_Cell_Measurement</pair>
  </dm_log_packet>
</root>
```

I tried to parse it using ElementTree but failed.

Here is my code:

```py
from xml.etree import ElementTree

class Log:
    def __init__(self,type_id=None):
        self.type_id=type_id
    def __str__(self):
        return self.type_id

roota=ElementTree.parse("file.xml")
log_file = roota.findall("dm_log_packet")

lo = []
for aa in log_file:
    log = Log()
    log.type_id = aa.find("type_id").text
    lo.append(log)
```

I expect to parse each pair, but it can't do it like I have a `<type_id>...</type_id>` pair.

Comment: You need to describe your expected output and the error you see, if any, or the output you currently get instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

```
xml = """
  <root>
     <dm_log_packet>
         <pair key ="type_id">LTE_PHY_Serv_Cell_Measurement</pair>
    </dm_log_packet>
  </root>
  """

soup_obj = BeautifulSoup(xml)
soup_obj.html.body.foo.bar.findAll('type')[0]['foobar']
```

Output will

> '1'

[More Descriptive Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912434/how-do-i-parse-xml-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

`.find()` and `.findall()` expect XPath as arguments, plain strings like `"dm_log_packet"` will not find anything.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

class Log:
    def __init__(self, type_id=None):
        self.type_id=type_id

    def __str__(self):
        return self.type_id

tree = ElementTree.parse("file.xml")
lo = []

for dm_log_packet in tree.findall(".//dm_log_packet"):
    pair = dm_log_packet.find("./pair/[@key='type_id']")
    if pair is not None:
        lo.append(Log(pair.text))
```

Note that `dm_log_packet.find("./pair/[@key='type_id']")` will return `None` when there is no `<pair key="type_id">`, hence the extra check.